# How to use a zipped Maven artifact as wsdlArtifact in Apache CXF

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to generate Java code from WSDLs using the Apache CXF Maven plugin `cxf-codegen-plugin` where the WSDLs are contained in a Maven artifact of type `zip`.

At the moment, I fetch and unwrap the WSDLs using the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>some.company.service</groupId>
                        <artifactId>service-package</artifactId>
                        <version>${service-package.version}</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <classifier>wsdl</classifier>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/deps</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, the Apache CXF codegen plugin allows to provide the artifact directly using `wsdlArtifact` and making the dependency plugin redundant:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdlArtifact>
                            <groupId>some.company.service</groupId>
                            <artifactId>service-package</artifactId>
                            <version>${service-package.version}</version>
                        </wsdlArtifact>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this case this won't work and I get the error:

```bash
Failed to resolve WSDL artifact some.company.service:service-package:0.0.1
```

If I change the artifact definition to:

```xml
<wsdlArtifact>
    <groupId>some.company.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-package</artifactId>
    <version>${service-package.version}</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <classifier>wsdl</classifier>
</wsdlArtifact>
```

The plugin throws an exception during processing:

```bash
[...]
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x56 (at char #12, byte #-1)
[...]
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x56 (at char #12, byte #-1)
```

To me it seems that the plugin is not able to parse an artifact of type `zip`. Correct? Is there any solution to achieve this using the codegen plugin only or do I need the dependency plugin?

If I could parse the WSDL artifact somehow, is it possible to include / exclude certain WSDL for code generation?